# Is there a way to put absolute positioning on text?

Tags: html, css, text, positioning

I would like to use the top:x; or bottom:x; rules but I have no idea how to do that to the H1 text. I would appreciate if someone could help. I tried relative positioning and then putting absolute positioning on the text. I'm new to css so I'm not sure what to do. I need to put more text there and then eventually put form text there as well but not have anything covered by the header lol.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project3</title>
</head>
<style>
*{
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:0;
}
header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height:100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee;
  width:100%;
  justify-content:space-between;
  z-index:2;
}
#header-img{
}
#logo{
  height:100px;
}
#nav-bar{
}
nav > ul{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  flex-direction:row;
  width:60vw;
  list-style-type:none;
}
nav > ul > li{
  border:black 2px solid;
  padding:30px;
}
.nav-link{
}

/*above this is the navbar and it's contents*/
body{
  height:100%;
}
.container{
  display:grid;
  height:100%;
  grid-template-areas:
  "left main right"
  "mleft mmain mright"
  "bleft bmain bright";
  grid-template-columns:15% 70% 15%;
  grid-template-rows:repeat(3, 500px);
}
.left{
  grid-area:left;
}
.main{
  grid-area:main;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}
.right{
  grid-area:right;
}
.main > iframe{
}
.mleft{
  grid-area:mleft;
}
.mmain{
  grid-area:mmain;
  justify-content:center;
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
}
.mright{
  grid-area:mright;
}
.bleft{
  grid-area:bleft;
}
.bmain{
  grid-area:bmain;
}
.bright{
  grid-area:bright;
}
#video{
}
</style>
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <div id="header-img">
            <img id="logo" src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/26-262191_like-us-on-facebook-logo-facebook-image-like.png" alt="lol getcho mouse off me bitch">
        </div>
        <nav id="nav-bar">
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#here">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#there">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#over">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>       
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="main"><h1>(TEXT I WANT TO POSITION)</h1></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
        <div class="mleft"></div>
        <div class="mmain"> <iframe id="video"style="position:absolute;bottom:0;" width="600" height="315"src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"></iframe> </div>
        <div class="mright"></div>
        <div class="bleft"></div>
        <div class="bmain"></div>
        <div class="bright"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Minal Chauhan what did you change?

Comment: add to the .main{flex-direction:column;} and then justify it. and you can try sticky instead of fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to understand how the positioning works.
This link will be helpful to you.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning

As you said you want to put the text inside the div. So firstly apply relative position to that div.

```
div {
  position: relative;
}
```

Then apply absolute positioning to the h1 tag with top or bottom property.

```
div > h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
}
```

You can check the link below, I've created this pen to demonstrate the use.
https://codepen.io/prathameshkoshti/pen/OJXBeqp

Comment: I just wanna say this actually helped me so much in learning positioning